# Used to have or used to had

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

> 1. I miss the discussions we used to have.
> 2. I miss the discussions we used to had.

Please give the reason why one of the above is correct.

Comment: You need the plain (base) form "have". "Used" requires an infinitival clause as complement (btw, the "to" belongs with "have, not "used").

Answer (score 3):

We use the simple form of the verb after "used to", so your first sentence is correct.

> I miss the discussions we used to have.

Answer (score 0):

The X in *used to X* is an infinitive.

Infinitives are always the base or main form of a verb without exception.

Keep in mind *used to have had* is possible, contracted to *used to've had* and if spoken by someone not clear in their enunciation it may sound like *used to had*.